# Android. How to show circle of radio button

Tags: android, radio-button

I need programatically hide and show circle of radio button. Here is my code:

```
private fun hideCircle() {
        rbTest.buttonDrawable = null
        rbTest.isClickable = false
    }
```

How to return the previous look of the radio button with circle.
I have a solution, but it works with 23 api:

```
  private var drawable: Drawable? = null
   drawable = rbTest.buttonDrawable
 private fun showCircle() {
        rbTest.buttonDrawable = drawable
        rbTest.isClickable = true
    }
```

But I need to do this starting from 19 api. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a drawable for the radio button like this. You can edit this drawable to suit your specifications.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
  android:bottom="3dp"
  android:left="3dp"
  android:right="3dp"
  android:top="1dp">

  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radio_button_checked_24dp" android:state_checked="true" >
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_radio_button_unchecked_24dp" android:state_checked="false">
    </item>
  </selector>

</item>
</layer-list>
```

Then programmatically int your Activity do

```
RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
radioButton.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.radio_button);
```